# Random perturbation of a value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, normal-distribution

Let's say I have a value 100 and I want to perturb this value randomly by 1% based on a normal distribution. How could I do this in MATLAB? I seem to have some confusion with `randn` etc.

I have used `randn` so far but I do not seem to be inside this 1% threshold all the time.

Comment: Pl share your work that you have done so far.

Comment: The normal distribution has no limits. If you want normally distributed noise, you have to accept that very rarely the deviation will be huge.

Comment: So that means that if I want to use randn then I can't escape having values that exceed the 1% threshold?

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "perturb this value randomly by 1% based on a normal distribution". For example, you might want a normal distribution with a _standard deviation_ equal to 1% the original value. But as Cris said, the normal distribution is unbounded, and sio it is incompatible with your idea of "1% threshold"

Comment: so you are asking for a 99% confidence normal distribution right? please confirm that what you are seeking, on average, is that only 1:100 samples out of the, 67% confidence interval, out of 95% confidence interval? or 99% confidence? you need to define the 'sharpness' of the normal distribution, a percentage is not enough. It would be if you had chosen for insrance a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the normal distribution `randn` is unbounded, it does not give values in the range `[0,1]` like `rand` does.

This paper offers a good explanation of the "tool" you'll need, which is the *truncated* normal distribution: [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/presentations/truncated_normal.pdf](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/presentations/truncated_normal.pdf)

> Informally, the truncated normal probability density function is defined in two steps. We choose a general normal PDF by specifying parameters µ and σ, and then a truncation range (a, b). The PDF associated with the general normal distribution is modified by setting values outside the range to zero, and uniformly scaling the values inside the range so that the total integral is 1.

This explicitly sets the function output to 0 outside your bounded range, and scales it by the difference of the cumulative distribution evaluated at `b` and `a`. Note that the standard deviation of this new distribution will not be the same as the original standard deviation, although if we choose symmetrical `a` and `b` around the mean then that should remain unchanged.

I'm going to skip the maths and implement one suggested sampling method from the linked literature which simply "imposes the truncation interval by rejection" with the following condition:

```
repeat:
    p = rand()
    x = Ф⁻¹(µ, σ; p)
until (a ≤ x ≤ b)
```

Where `Ф⁻¹(µ, σ; p)` is the inverse CDF of your normal distribution with mean `µ` and standard deviation `σ`, and `rand()` generates a *uniform* random number. MATLAB has an in-built function for sampling the inverse CDF if you have the Statistics toolbox: `icdf('normal',p,mu,sigma)`

So we can write a function like

```
function r = normrndt( mu, sigma, a, b, varargin )
% Output values in the truncated normal distribution, equivalent syntax to
% normrnd( mu, sigma, sz1, sz2, ... szN )
% But constrained to interval [a,b]

    % Start with uniform random values
    r = rand(varargin{:});
    % Feed them into the inverse CDF
    r = icdf('normal',r,mu,sigma);

    % Impose truncation interval by rejection
    % Repeating the above step per value if outside range
    for ii = 1:numel(r)
        while r(ii) < a || r(ii) > b
            r(ii) = icdf('normal',rand(),mu,sigma);
        end
    end
end
```

Testing this for different values of sigma, and a symmetrical distribution around mean `0` and interval `[-1,1]`. For your example, you could add these values to a base value of `100`:

```
sigma = 0.4; % standard deviation of normal dist
N = 1e5;     % number of points to sample
n = normrnd(0,sigma,N,1);        % Generate "proper" normally distributed values
nt = normrndt(0,sigma,-1,1,N,1); % Generate truncated normally distributed values

% Plot the results for comparison
edges = linspace(-sigma*5, sigma*5, 100); % bin edges for histo
figure; histogram( n, edges ); hold on; histogram( nt, edges ) % plot overlay of outputs
```

You can see that for sigma values where the truncation interval lies several standard deviations away from the mean, there is hardly any change to the distribution. However as the standard deviation gets closer to the boundary we see the distribution become less and less "normal" looking.

[image: comparison for various sigma]